# Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint ''. Cannot insert duplicate key in object ''

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to create `Match` between two `User`'s. However i'm getting this error

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
 ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Violation of PRIMARY KEY "PK_Users" constraint. Cannot insert duplicate key into object 'dbo.Users'. Duplicate key value: (0c7a0cdc-a7ba-4cf8-ade2-0cef44761597).
```

I have this entities

```
public class Match
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public User LikedUser { get; set; }
    public bool Matched { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class User
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public Guid CityId { get; set; }
    public City City { get; set; }
    public Guid GenderId { get; set; }
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Match> Matches { get; set; } = new HashSet<Match>();
    public ICollection<Match> LikedBy { get; set; } = new HashSet<Match>();
}
```

That's unfinished method i just want to check if it would create `Match` or not

```
public async Task<Guid> Handle(CreateMatchCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var liker = await _unitOfWork.UserRepository.FindByIdAsync(request.Dto.Liker);
    var liked = await _unitOfWork.UserRepository.FindByIdAsync(request.Dto.Liked);

    var match = new Match { LikedUser = liked, User = liker };

    var matchId = await _unitOfWork.MatchRepository.CreateAsync(match);
    await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);

    return matchId;
}
```

MatchRepository

```
public async Task<Guid> CreateAsync(Match match)
{
    var matchEntity = _mapper.Map<MatchEntity>(match);
    await _context.Matches.AddAsync(matchEntity);

    return matchEntity.Id;
}
```

UserRepository

```
public async Task<User> FindByIdAsync(Guid guid)
    {
        var user = await _context.Users
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == guid);
        if (user == null) throw new NotFoundException(typeof(User), guid);

        _context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Detached;
        return _mapper.Map<User>(user);
    }
```

Why i'm getting this error?

Comment: Does the match table have a primary key of the liker and liked? If so, it's demanding that the primary key be unique . . . and what you're attempting to do has already been done . . . in other words, the liker and liked combo in the match table is already present and cannot be created a second time.

Comment: @VicF Match table has only 1 primary key and it's Id column

Comment: @VicF Duplicate key value in error it's from liker's Id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is what will actually happen to you, the reason is that both the user and the second user will be considered new objects.  What you will do is the following: add the UserId and LikedUserId in the Match, and save the new ones as follows:

var match = new Match { LikedUserId = liked.Id, UserId = liker.Id };

Comment: Thank you, but it only works in that way? I don't have any other options? If so why i should create one-to-many relationship without explicitly specifying ForeignKey?

Comment: Read about the convention and configuration.  They are considered the basis for the work of the EF.

Answer (score 0):

In userRepository, try removing this line.

```
public async Task<User> FindByIdAsync(Guid guid)
    {
        var user = await _context.Users
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == guid);
        if (user == null) throw new NotFoundException(typeof(User), guid);

        //_context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Detached; <-- Remove this
        return _mapper.Map<User>(user);
    }
```

So instead of tracking the `Liked` and `Like` users as new object, we will keep tracking them as an existing objects that are fetch from database, so EF Core will just update the foreign key in the Match entity automatically.

Edit : Since first solution didn't work, you can also try like this to automatically attached it:

```
public async Task<Guid> Handle(CreateMatchCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var liker = await _unitOfWork.UserRepository.FindByIdAsync(request.Dto.Liker);
    var liked = await _unitOfWork.UserRepository.FindByIdAsync(request.Dto.Liked);

_unitOfWork.Entry(liker).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
_unitOfWork.Entry(liked).State = EntityState.Unchanged;

    var match = new Match { LikedUser = liked, User = liker };

    var matchId = await 
    
     
    _unitOfWork.MatchRepository.CreateAsync(match);
    await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);

    return matchId;
}
```

So we will tell EF Core that entity `Liker` and `Liked` are existing entities from database, and no need for it to be reinserted. Just update the `Match` foreign keys to point to the `Liker` and `Liked` entities

Comment: i tried that and had errors about tracking user with same id. that's why i added that line

Comment: Okk, see my edits